# String compare performance system-verilog

Tags: performance, system-verilog

I was wondering if there was a performance difference in system-verilog when doing a string compare when using these two different methods:

```
1. str.compare(other_str);

2. str == other_str
```

If there is a difference, why is there a difference, and where did you get your information from?

Comment: They don't output the same thing, so a performance comparison would probably be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a lot more factors that might affect performance than what you have shown here. Realize that SystemVerilog comes from the merging of multiple languages. Sometimes there are duplication of features which, for historical reasons, prevented removal of the redundancies.

The Questions are:

- is the compiler sophisticated enough to generate the same
  implementation for both?
- if not, do some conditions favor one implementation over another? For example: characterization of the variable types, or storage class of the variables.
- and do those conditions affect the compilers ability in generating the same code for both?